# How do I ignore null value from date field when pulling into VB?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to populate a DateTimePicker on a Form. But some of the date fields are null so I get an error when running. Yes I could have 3 try catch statements for all three of the DateTimePickers, but I am looking for a cleaner way to do it.

I tried setting the value by passing in the data to a function that has a try catch in it, but the error is coming when the data is actually read.

ERROR: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid

---

```
dtpReturnDate.Value = GetDate(newEngineSelection.Item("engineReturnDate"))
```

---

```
Private Function GetDate(newDate As Date)

    Dim datNewDate As Date

    Try
        datNewDate = newDate
    Catch ex As Exception
        datNewDate = New Date(2000, 1, 1)
    End Try

    Return datNewDate

End Function
```

Comment: What's the datatype of newEngineSelection? Sometime these classes have a newEngineSelection.IsDbNull("engineReturnDate") which you could use instead.

Comment: newEngineSelection is a DataRow

Comment: You could use the [IsNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fwatee0(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [IsNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fwatee0(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

```
If newEngineSelection.IsNull("engineReturnDate") Then
    dtpReturnDate.Value = New Date(2000, 1, 1)
Else
    dtpReturnDate.Value = CDate(newEngineSelection.Item("engineReturnDate"))
End If
```

Comment: This would totally work, but then I am in the same boat as the try catch. I am really wondering if there is a way to do it with less code.

Comment: There's a big difference between an If statement and a Try/Catch. There isn't much you can do here unless you put the if statement in a function.